# Can anyone help me with a GROUP BY issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
tc.dv_task,
tc.dv_ci_item,
     STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + lob.name
        FROM u_cmdb_ci_line_of_business lob
        where lob.sys_id = tc.ci_item
        GROUP BY tc.dv_task
        FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') AS LOBs
FROM task_ci tc
INNER JOIN u_cmdb_ci_line_of_business lob on tc.ci_item = lob.sys_id
```

It returns the following error: Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4505220) - 13.0.5101.9 (X64)

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: I have two tables task_ci (tc) and u_cmdb_line_of_business (lob). The tables join by tc.ci_item = lob.sys_id. For each dv_task on the tc table, I want one line that lists, in a comma-separated field, the related ci_items from the lob table. That's why I'm trying to group by dv_task.

```
If I take out the group by, I get this:
tc.dv_task   LOBs (Stuff field)
123456       lob.ci_item 1 
123456       lob.ci_item 2
```

I want this:
dv_task    LOBs (Stuff field)
123456      lob. ci_item 1, lob.ci_item 2

But when I add that group by, as an attempt to get things in one row, I get that error. Hope that makes sense.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: 03/23

Okay, I got it, I just changed it up to substring like this

```
select 
inc.number,
substring((select ', ' + lob.name from task_ci tc 
                join u_cmdb_ci_line_of_business lob on lob.sys_id = tc.ci_item 
                where inc.sys_id = tc.task
                for XML PATH('')),2,1000) as lob_sysid                
from incident inc
where inc.number = 'INC1157655'
```

I'm still not sure what I was doing wrong with the STUFF but I'll try it with the different table to see how it works.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: ...and the database is...?

Comment: @TheImpaler, sorry, it's  Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4505220) - 13.0.5101.9 (X64)

Comment: You're selecting from `u_cmdb_ci_line_of_business`, but you're trying to group by something that is not in the reach of the query. What is the idea behind your `GROUP BY`? Can you edit your Question to reflect what you expect the inner `SQL` to return and what you'd like to happen when there are multiple rows for one `tc.ci_item`, or if there even are multiple rows?

Comment: @Scratte, I've added a description of what I'm trying to do. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Ok. My next question is what are you trying to do with `STUFF`? Take out the second character of the result? Or did I misunderstand and the example is your excepted end result? Can you also supply with the exact SQL where you "take out the group by"?

Comment: I'm confused. You're select only one column from your inner SQL and 3 columns from your outer SQL, but your examples show two columns. Please clarify. Kindly also format your Question, so normal text isn't in code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `JOIN` in the outer query:

```
SELECT tc.dv_task, tc.dv_ci_item,
     STUFF((SELECT ',' + lob.name
            FROM u_cmdb_ci_line_of_business lob
            WHERE lob.sys_id = tc.ci_item
            FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 1, '') AS LOBs
FROM task_ci tc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it, I just changed it up to substring like this

```
select 
inc.number,
substring((select ', ' + lob.name from task_ci tc 
                join u_cmdb_ci_line_of_business lob on lob.sys_id = tc.ci_item 
                where inc.sys_id = tc.task
                for XML PATH('')),2,1000) as lob_sysid                
from incident inc
where inc.number = 'INC1157655'
```

I'm still not sure what I was doing wrong with the STUFF but I'll try it with the different table to see how it works.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's no reason why you can't use STUFF in your query.